# ui:scrollerWrapper not working in Salesforce1

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, lightning-design-system, scrolling, winter17

Newly added Lightning component in the Winter '17, ui:scrollerWrapper which claims to create a container that enables native scrolling in Salesforce1 is not working in Salesforce1 app.

**CODE:** (to reproduce the issue in **Winter '17** pre-release org)

**Component:-**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable, flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
            <div class="mainWrap">
                <ui:scrollerWrapper class="sWrapTest">
                    <ul class="testDiv">        
                       <li>In the Winter ’17 release, many of your favorite features 
                           are easier to use than ever before. 
                       </li>
                       <li>Lightning Experience has a brand new                      
                           navigation bar and lots of critical sales,
                           service, and analytics capabilities. 
                       </li>
                       <li>You’ve got more options for managing customer and partner
                           communities, running your business from your phone, 
                           and keeping your data and your users secure. 
                       </li>
                       <li>Not to mention plentiful new
                           customization and app development features, 
                           including custom Lightning apps.
                       </li>                      
                       <li>Other features require direct action by an administrator 
                           before users can benefit from the new functionality.
                       </li>
                       <li>If a key feature is also available in Salesforce1, 
                           our mobile app, we mention that in the feature description. 
                       </li>
                       <li>ui:scrollerWrapper
                           Creates a container that enables native scrolling in 
                           Salesforce1.
                       </li>

                    </ul>
                </ui:scrollerWrapper>
            </div>
        </aura:component>
```

**Style:-**

```
.THIS .sWrapTest {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
```

ui:scrollerWrapper is not working in the Salesforce1 app. I've tested the same in iPad, iPhone and android devices.

It works fine in Chrome browser, when opened in device view simulator, when the div is dragged downwards or towards the right.

But I'm not able to scroll the contents inside ui:scrollerWrapper in the Salesforce1 app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue no longer exists.  Checking in the Winter 17 release, it is working.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/57159)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Srinivas Araru for pointing this out. Yes, the scroll is now working. :)

Comment: @DaveHumm Since there are no additional details or changes to the code to be made for posting answer for fixing this issue, I've accepted this answer.The code, which I've posted in my question is currently working in Winter '17 org. Earlier the scroll did not work in Salesforce1 app in mobile devices.

Comment: Still not a good answer - see [answer].

Comment: @DaveHumm Then I would be very much obliged if you could edit this answer and make it a "good answer" and guide the person who answered the question to write more "good" answers. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer . Hope you have read " Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful...... Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better." This answer was helpful for me and it answered the question too.

Comment: Asking - does this still exist is not right in an answer. It is fine to say the that the issue is now resolved and if it cannot be reproduced in a release which release it is now working in.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot @DaveHumm for the correction. :)